Dugundji Extension Theorem
I'm working through Dugundji's extension of Tietze's Theorem, and I'm having difficulty verifying that the provided canonical cover satisfies condition 2.13. as denoted below.

I have a mental image of it, but I'm having difficulty formulating in words or a viable proof.

Hint: if we take away from $W$ the  closures of those $U$ meeting both $W$ and $X\setminus W$, we still get an open neighborhood of $a$, since $\{U\}$ is locally finite and closure preserves union in a locally finite family.

Good approach, but i figured out a simpler way

I was vastly overthinking it.
Let $W$ be a neighborhood containing $a$, and let $D_r(a)\subset W$ be an open ball of radius $r$ centered at $a$.
Let $a \in W' = D_{r/3}(a) \subset W$. If some $U \in \mathcal{U}$ has nonempty intersection with $W'$, then let $y$ be a point in this intersection. $U$ is contained in some $S_x$, thus $S_x \cap W' \ni y$.
Since $d(x,y)\le \mathrm{diam}(S_x) < \frac{1}{2} d(x,A)\le \frac{1}{2}d(x,a)$, and $d(y,a)<\frac{r}{3}$, we have the following:
\begin{equation}
d(x,a) \le d(x,y) + d(y,a) < \frac{1}{2}d(x,a) + \frac{r}{3}\,,
\end{equation}
which gives us $d(x,a)< \frac{2r}{3}$. Thus, we have a bound on $\mathrm{diam}(S_x)$, namely, $\frac{r}{3}$.
Finally, if $z \in S_x$, we have the following:
\begin{align*}
d(z,a) \le d(z,x) + d(x,a) < r\, .
\end{align*}
Therefore, $U \subset S_x \subset D_r(a)\subset W$.
$\Box$
